# Two outputs in matlab function

Tags: matlab

I'm calling a function with 2 outputs: 2 vectors of different size.

I need to use 2 vector of different size (outside of the function) that are calculate inside of the function.

How can I use both vectors out of that function?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Lets call the output vectors $X$ and $Y$, say we want to add them (I know they are of different size but this is hypothetical), so we want $X+Y$.

Write the function `firstcode` and execute the script:

```
[X,Y]=firstcode;

Z=X+Y;

disp(Z)
```

Comment: You can properly typeset code using the curly braces option {}. This corresponds to putting the code between ` marks inline and indenting by four spaces for block code.

Comment: Would you mind fitting it for me so I can see?